# Evaluation Method or Evaluation Methodology

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

In a research domain, evaluation part is itself challenging, and thus we are proposing a way of doing the evaluation in that domain (i.e. determining what inputs should be given to the system and what outputs should be expected). Should we call what we are proposing an "evaluation method" or an "evaluation methodology"?

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23673/differences-between-methods-methodologies-and-paradigms

Comment: To make it simple, the "methodology" describes the principles of the evaluation technics, whilst the "method" refers to the evaluation process.

Comment: But still I can't decide which one is the correct choice in this context