# Differences between “Approach,” "Perspective," and “Paradigm”

Tags: word-choice, differences, synonyms, technical

My question is related to this one: [Differences between “methods”, “methodologies” and “paradigms”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23673/differences-between-methods-methodologies-and-paradigms)

In lectures, we learned

> In statistical practice, there are two main *schools of thought* or
> **paradigms**:
>
> 1. frequentist
> 2. Bayesian

Moreover, on the shelf we have books with titles like *Decision Analysis: A Bayesian **Approach*** or *Machine Learning: A Bayesian and Optimization **Perspective***

I was wondering what are the differences between *Approach*, *Perspective*, and *Paradigms*?

Comment: Approach is more action-oriented that perspective which is like a view point. E.g., He approaches the problems differently. His thoughts/ view points/ perspectives are different. Paradigm is usually heard in management studies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Approach" implies a hands-on style. "Perspective" is more theoretical. "Paradigm" is similar to perspective, but implies that some specific model will be used, i.e., it will be a "systematic" perspective.

- What's your approach to saving money? (How do you do it?)
- What's your perspective on saving money? (How do you look at it?)
- What's your money saving paradigm? (What's the actual model?)

Sometimes these three terms are used interchangeably.

Source: my experience as a CS/Math undergrad.